# OAuth: what information should I store in tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am creating an OAuth server which issues tokens to users. However, I don't want to store tokens in the database, and I want the processing to be fast.

What I'm thinking is to include various information in the token, so that when I decrypt it, the information is already enough to check for permissions and scopes.

I'm a little worried about the token's length growing as I add more scopes.

Is this a good idea? If not, what can you recommend?

Comment: Possible duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135157/what-to-use-to-generate-oauth-2-access-token .

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking here is about InMemoryTokenStore which is the default implementation. Also Oauth2 already maintains the information required to check permissions and scopes in token in form of different access roles provided by authorization server to various clients. I think you don't need to explicitly store anything in token.